# Getting random output json

Tags: php, json, random, youtube-api

I trying to get a youtube channel banner from the youtube api.
But this is very weird.

I use this code:

```
$json1 = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/partners/$channel/branding/default?key=[api-key]&alt=json");
$data1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$banner = $data1['entry']['yt$option'][15]['$t'];
echo $banner;
```

Now the weird thing, when i refresh te page i get everytime a new value. but sometimes it will stay one value and thats what i need but after some thime the value is changing...

This is the json code:

```
{
   "version":"1.0",
   "encoding":"UTF-8",
   "entry":{
      "xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
      "xmlns$yt":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007",
      "id":{
         "$t":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/partners/rebasenetwork/branding/default"
  },
  "published":{
     "$t":"2014-02-28T22:08:37.000Z"
  },
  "updated":{
     "$t":"2014-02-28T22:08:37.000Z"
  },
  "category":[
     {
        "scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
        "term":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#branding"
     }
  ],
  "link":[
     {
        "rel":"self",
        "type":"application/atom+xml",
        "href":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/partners/rebasenetwork/branding/default"
     },
     {
        "rel":"edit",
        "type":"application/atom+xml",
        "href":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/partners/rebasenetwork/branding/default"
     }
  ],
  "yt$option":[
     {
        "$t":"0",
        "name":"channel.banner.image_height.int"
     },
     {
        "$t":"http://i1.ytimg.com/u/Yd24MzwIk2gLiv79JNPGSA/channels4_mobile_banner_hd.jpg?v=52d6ad2b",
        "name":"channel.banner.mobile.hd.image.url"
     },
     {
        "$t":"http://i1.ytimg.com/u/Yd24MzwIk2gLiv79JNPGSA/channels4_tablet_banner.jpg?v=52d6ad2b",
        "name":"channel.banner.tablet.medium.image.url"
     },
     {
        "$t":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-6xCc8OBY5Qk/UtatKX2WY3I/AAAAAAAAAAY/6-vpTOgd0yU/w854-fcrop64=1,00000000ffffffff/channels4_banner.jpg",
        "name":"channel.banner.tv.low.image.url"
     },
     {
        "$t":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-6xCc8OBY5Qk/UtatKX2WY3I/AAAAAAAAAAY/6-vpTOgd0yU/w1280-fcrop64=1,00000000ffffffff/channels4_banner.jpg",
        "name":"channel.banner.tv.medium.image.url"
     },
     {
        "$t":"#000000",
        "name":"channel.global.color"
     },
     {
        "$t":"http://i1.ytimg.com/u/Yd24MzwIk2gLiv79JNPGSA/channels4_banner.jpg?v=52d6ad2b",
        "name":"channel.banner.image.url"
     },
     {
        "$t":"http://i1.ytimg.com/u/Yd24MzwIk2gLiv79JNPGSA/channels4_mobile_banner_low.jpg?v=52d6ad2b",
        "name":"channel.banner.mobile.low.image.url"
     },
     {
        "$t":"True",
        "name":"channel.modules.show_comments.bool"
     },
     {
        "$t":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-6xCc8OBY5Qk/UtatKX2WY3I/AAAAAAAAAAY/6-vpTOgd0yU/w2120-fcrop64=1,00000000ffffffff/channels4_banner.jpg",
        "name":"channel.banner.tv.image.url"
     },
     {
        "$t":"http://i1.ytimg.com/u/Yd24MzwIk2gLiv79JNPGSA/channels4_tablet_banner_hd.jpg?v=52d6ad2b",
        "name":"channel.banner.tablet.hd.image.url"
     },
     {
        "$t":"Welcome to our network Channel. We help Youtubers to earn money and grow with their channel. Being famous on youtube is one of the things you dream about, isn't it? Let us help make your dreams true!\n\nWith us you can choose your own partnership, You also select what you want to earn from your youtube channel! Are you ready to start growing? Partner Now!",
        "name":"channel.global.description.string"
     },
     {
        "$t":"http://i1.ytimg.com/u/Yd24MzwIk2gLiv79JNPGSA/channels4_mobile_banner_medium_hd.jpg?v=52d6ad2b",
        "name":"channel.banner.mobile.medium_hd.image.url"
     },
     {
        "$t":"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-6xCc8OBY5Qk/UtatKX2WY3I/AAAAAAAAAAY/6-vpTOgd0yU/w1920-fcrop64=1,00000000ffffffff/channels4_banner.jpg",
        "name":"channel.banner.tv.high.image.url"
     },
     {
        "$t":"http://i1.ytimg.com/u/Yd24MzwIk2gLiv79JNPGSA/channels4_mobile_banner.jpg?v=52d6ad2b",
        "name":"channel.banner.mobile.medium.image.url"
     },
     {
        "$t":"http://i1.ytimg.com/u/Yd24MzwIk2gLiv79JNPGSA/channels4_mobile_banner.jpg?v=52d6ad2b",
        "name":"channel.banner.mobile.image.url"
     },
     {
        "$t":"True",
        "name":"channel.related_channels.show.bool"
     },
     {
        "$t":"KQvIpdiWrSI",
        "name":"channel.unsubscribed_trailer.video_id.string"
     },
     {
        "$t":"http://i1.ytimg.com/u/Yd24MzwIk2gLiv79JNPGSA/channels4_tablet_banner_extra_hd.jpg?v=52d6ad2b",
        "name":"channel.banner.tablet.extra_hd.image.url"
     },
     {
        "$t":"http://i1.ytimg.com/u/Yd24MzwIk2gLiv79JNPGSA/channels4_tablet_banner_low.jpg?v=52d6ad2b",
        "name":"channel.banner.tablet.low.image.url"
     },
     {
        "$t":"True",
        "name":"channel.modules.moderate_comments.bool"
     },
     {
        "$t":"Network partner partnership rebase network pewdiepie",
        "name":"channel.global.keywords.string"
     },
     {
        "$t":"Rebase Network",
        "name":"channel.global.title.string"
     },
     {
        "$t":"http://i1.ytimg.com/u/Yd24MzwIk2gLiv79JNPGSA/channels4_mobile_banner_extra_hd.jpg?v=52d6ad2b",
        "name":"channel.banner.mobile.extra_hd.image.url"
     }
  ]
   }
}
```

This is the one i need(just the url):

```
         {
  "$t":"http://i1.ytimg.com/u/Yd24MzwIk2gLiv79JNPGSA/channels4_tablet_banner_extra_hd.jpg?v=52d6ad2b",
        "name":"channel.banner.tablet.extra_hd.image.url"
     },
```

Can someone help me please? i really don't understand why it's changing the value every refresh..

Comment: does the name of the item stay the same? "name":"channel.banner.tablet.extra_hd.image.url"

Comment: Do you mean the results are being returned in a different order?  Or that the image name is different?  If the image name is different, I don't really know what to tell you.  If the order is different, we can find the item and pull it out, regardless of its position.

Comment: The objects in the array `yt$option` appear to be idenified by their `name` property, not by their position in the array. Do not assume that the object you need is always at index `15`. It's a stupid way to organize their data, but that's what you'll have to work around.

Comment: @Quixrick The json stays the same but the results are every refresh different..

Comment: @marabutt everything stays the same, but the results are every refresh different

Comment: is there not a way to say: get $t where name = channel.banner.tablet.extra_hd.image.url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the results and print out the one where the name matches `channel.banner.mobile.extra_hd.image.url`

```
$data1 = json_decode($json1, true);

foreach ($data1['entry']['yt$option'] AS $banner) {

    if ($banner['name'] == 'channel.banner.mobile.extra_hd.image.url') {
        print $banner['$t'];
    }

}
```